# Как вывести сообщение пользователю что форма отправлена?

Tags: javascript, html, html-form

Только начинаю осваивать web-разработку, поэтому ищу ответа здесь

[codepan](http://codepen.io/Tarasovych/pen/RRRqNy)

Будет ли проще сделать всплывающее окно? Или редирект на страницу с сообщением что форма отправлена

```
<body>
    <div class="tablebg">   
        <div class="table2">
            <form action="" method="POST" id="formID">
                <div class="leftblock">
                    <div class="nameblock">
                        <input name="name" type="name" placeholder="NAME" required="true">
                    </div>
                    <div class="emailblock">
                        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="EMAIL" required="true">
                    </div>
                    <div class="webblock">
                        <input name="web" type="url" placeholder="WEB" required="true" pattern="https?://.+" >
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="rightblock">
                    <div class="messageblock">
                        <textarea name="name" placeholder="MESSAGE" required="true" ></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sumbitblock">
                        <input type="submit" value="SEND" class="button">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: [xhr](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: мне пока сложно это освоить

Comment: Для начала стоит освоить js основы. При отправке кучи значений так как на коде выше не делается. `form` можно использовать для передачи коротких значений или отправки файлов. `required="true"` можно писать просто `required`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще сделать редирект. То есть, форма отправляется на сервер, пользователю отрисовывается новая страница с сообщением.
Пример обработки формы средствами PHP:
http://php.net/manual/ru/tutorial.forms.php

Правильнее  (точнее сказать современнее)- сделать Ajax запрос. сервер получет форму, а пользователь на той же странице видит уведомление об отправке.
Пример обработки формы средствами PHP Ajax запрос:
http://blog.ox2.ru/php/ajax-form/

В примерах на PHP используется переменная $_POST. То есть, форма должна использовать метод отправки `<form method="post">`. Подробнее о методах отправки можно прочитать тут https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#.D0.9C.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B4.D1.8B

Comment: Редирект - это с использование php? Может есть примеры кода? Или хотя бы структура, принцип работы

Comment: @Tarasovych, когда нажимаешь `SEND`, перекидывает на другую страницу. Поэтому придумали запросы, ссылку на которые я кинул в комментариях под вопросом. `ajax` без фреймворка `jquery` работать не будет. Для реализации советую разобраться с js и xhr

Comment: @Tarasovych в ответе добавил ссылки на примеры. В любом случае, форма при заполнении должна быть обработана на сервере. с использованием серверных языков программирования. таких как PHP, Java (не путать с JavaScript)